# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\faLink' on input line 1

Tags: hyperref

Above warning is killing me as I am not able to resolve it and it is occurring multiple times as I am using the same code through out my document. I have tried all the solution pitched in on stack-overflow but not able to resolve it.

So, ultimately I want to show a link icon in front of one of my section heading and for that I have written the following 2 lines of code:

```
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}

\section{2020\_conf\_chau\_multiply \href{https://drive.google.com/}{\faLink}}
```

However wherever I am putting the above section it is giving me the above mentioned error.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316816

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PDF bookmark has trouble with the special character (link symbol: `\faLink`). Based on

- [Math symbols in .pdf bookmarks tab not displaying correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316816) or
- [Hyperref package (token not allowed in a PDF string)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417073/) or
- [Ways to avoid 'Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string' warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430876) (please also have a look at Heiko's comment),

use the following as a starting point. The key is the `\texorpdfstring{LaTeX Version}{PDF Bookmark Version}` command. I will *not* comment on the topic of the usefulness of your section title :).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

% \texorpdfstring{LaTeX Version}{PDF Bookmark Version}
\section{%
    \texorpdfstring{%
                2020\_conf\_chau\_multiply \href{https://drive.google.com/}{\faLink}%
                }{%
                Bookmark Version%
            }%
        }

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Otherwise, you get the following warning:

[image]

> ```
> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed
> in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\faLink' on input line 18.
> ```